# Does anyone know of a substitute, or native application, for notes and notebooks in Ubuntu?

Tags: software-recommendation, notes, evernote

I've been testing Evernote for a month.
I believe that it has a perfect design, adequate functionalities that adapt well to my workflow.

Mainly the notes are academic notes, drafts of documents and personal and family annotations.

What I'm looking for basically is:

- Cloud-based
- Synchronization with mobiles
- Notes with styles and organization in folders or notebooks

Answer (score 0):

[Organon](https://extensions.libreoffice.org/extensions/organon-1) is free software with the formatting capability you want (it piggybacks on Libre Office Write), comes in a Linux native version, and coupled with documents stored on Dropbox or Google Drive will give the cloud features you want.  I can't say whether it's directly compatible with other notes apps (especially on Android or iOS), because I don't use it that way.

Comment: Is it an extension of LibreOffice?

Comment: That does seem to be what they call it.  I've had it a while, didn't recall.  Editing in a link in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you're happy with Evernote, you may want to try **[Tusk](https://github.com/klaussinani/tusk)**.

> Tusk is an unofficial, featureful, open source, community-driven, free Evernote app used by people in more than 130 countries.

You can install Tusk (snap version) from the **Software** (store) application or by running the following command in Terminal

```
snap install tusk
```